Issue Installing SonarQube Extension on TFS Server (Version 16.131.28226.3)
I'm encountering an error while trying to install the SonarQube extension from the Azure Marketplace.I'm using TFS Server version 16.131.28226.3.
When I attempt to install the extension, I receive the following error message:
Something's gone wrong
We've encountered an error while downloading the extension. Please try again later.

I've tried restarting the TFS server and reattempting the installation, but the issue persists.
I would appreciate any guidance on troubleshooting this installation issue. I need the SonarQube extension to integrate it into my build pipeline.
Thanks in advance for your assistance!

I can reproduce the same on TFS2018(16.131.28226.3). It's a known issue from this 3rd-party extension and it has been reported to the extension publisher below:
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-extension-failed/114866

As per the extension compatibility :
The SonarQube extension for Azure DevOps 4.x is compatible with TFS2018

As a workaround, we can download the extension from github link: eg: SonarQube extension 4.19.0.

On local TFS, go to http://.../tfs/_gallery/manage page to upload the extension:

Then manually install the extension:

Extension installed:


Great . Let me implemnet this workaround

@TahamiRizwan, let me know if it works or you have any queries.

@TahamiRizwan, the workaround is manually download the V4 extension and install on on local TFS server. May i know if it works for you? Let me know if you have any queries.

@ wadezhau actually I am busy in some very urgent tasks. As soon as I got free for this I will implment and let you know ..
Thanks for your support

Thanks @TahamiRizwan. Let me know if you have any queries, glad to help.
